# remote: GitLab: Failed to authorize your Git request: internal API unreachable

Tags: git, gitlab

I am trying to push an existing Prestashop project to gitlab but I get following error:

```
{user}@{host}:/var/www/html/{project}# git push -u origin master
Password for 'https://{gitlab.com-user}@gitlab.com': 
Counting objects: 20891, done.
Compressing objects: 100% (14218/14218), done.
Writing objects: 100% (20888/20888), 168.58 MiB | 6.25 MiB/s, done.
Total 20888 (delta 5567), reused 20881 (delta 5563)
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (5567/5567), completed with 2 local objects.
remote: GitLab: Failed to authorize your Git request: internal API unreachable
To https://{gitlab.com-user}@gitlab.com/{project}/{project}.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://{gitlab.com-user}@gitlab.com/{project}/{project}.git'
```

My .gitignore file is:

```
# Private files
# The following files contain your database credentials and other personal data.

#config/settings.*.php

# Cache, temp and generated files
# The following files are generated by PrestaShop.

#admin-dev/autoupgrade/
admin*/autoupgrade/
/cache/
!/cache/index.php
!/cache/cachefs/index.php
!/cache/purifier/index.php
!/cache/push/index.php
!/cache/sandbox/index.php
!/cache/smarty/index.php
!/cache/tcpdf/index.php
config/xml/*.xml
/log/*
*sitemap.xml
themes/*/cache/
modules/*/config*.xml

# Site content
# The following folders contain product images, virtual products, CSV's, etc.

admin*/backups/
admin*/export/
admin*/import/
download/
/img/*
upload/
```

I use gitlab.com free account it's not installed on my server. Can it be size of project? Is there a size limit for a commit or a repo? Should I ignore any directory else?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: sounds like you should contact gitlab support. the problem is on their end, not yours

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. I am a free user, can I get support for this? and from where?

Comment: i think you can get free support here https://support.gitlab.com/hc/en-us/requests/new , its not your fault, but a bug with gitlab.com , after all. i'd imagine they'd be happy to hear about any gitlab.com usability bugs, as they want as many users as they can get, by the looks of it